# I am not able to write the x path

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

It is showing Exception in thread "main"

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable for the log in button of the freecrm.com

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver_2\\chromedriver2.exe");
            
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            
driver.get("https://freecrm.com");
             
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a//span[text()='Log In']")).click();
```

[image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhVpU.png)

Answer (score 1):

Error says, its unable to interact. When we look at UI once, When we hover on Login, button getting enabled (i.e. changing color to Green) to click. My suggestion is to do mouse move on to the element using Actions class with the same xpath what you tried and click using Actions class like:

new Actions(driver).moveToElement(By.xpath("//a//span[text()='Log In']")).click();

You can try this approach..

Answer (score -1):

Use the xpath as "//span[text()='Log In']". It will work